# Adding google translator to website

Tags: html, web, translation, google-translate

I want to add the google translator, or any other decent translators to my website. 
I do NOT want to translate my pages to another language. 
I want to add the box that is here: translate.google.com, to my website, so people can translate words and such through my website.

I've searched a lot, and found no answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the google translate API, sign in with your google account and read about it here: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/getting-started

Comment: Is using their API free?

Answer (score 1):

I use it and it is free, just sign up for it. For example, I put it on this site because at the church it's a log of old Greek people and most cannot read English. http://stnickporticons.com/ look right under the navbar. Choose your language selections once you sign up and then you will get code like this

```html
<div id="google_translate_element" style="padding:1em;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'el,en', autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying... But if you read my question correctly, I don't want to translate my page, I want to add this box here : translate.google.com
to my page.

Comment: you don't mean what mine looks like? https://s16.postimg.org/kbom21e0l/Capture.png with Chrome and Firefox I can click on any word and translate it on anyweb page, it's an add on to the browsers

Comment: No :) I dont want to translate pages. I want to a BOX that translates WORDS.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple way, I think

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="id-ID">
<body>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() { new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'id'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js? cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<p>Teks yang ingin Anda terjemahkan.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>

<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This comment doesn't answer the original question. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27795011)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Mohammadb It's not a new question, it's an answer and therefore it shouldn't be deleted. It might not be the best answer, but that's not a reason to delete it. See [this post by a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/4284627).